# Flutter web - Bloc doesn't receive events after Dio 404 error

Tags: flutter, web, bloc, dio

I have faced problem with adding events to Bloc object after previously encountering HTTP 404 response with Dio library.

I've created simple example to show the problem. 
It allows user to click the button. When it happens, event is generated and added to the bloc object. 
Bloc tries to call some URL that doesn't exist, getting HTTP 404 error. Now, DioError is properly caught with try-catch, error message is displayed in on the screen, however, when running on web, when I try to execute the same flow again then bloc object doesn't get this event (call to BlocProvider.of(context).add(Event()) has effect), mapEventToState method is never called again on MyBloc object and there is no error (apart from failed HTTP request displayed in browser's console)

Note: It works fine on Android and iOS, but not on web

My dependencies (from pubspec.yaml)

```
  bloc: 4.0.0
  flutter_bloc: 4.0.0
  dio: 3.0.9
```

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Dio web error',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => MyBloc(),
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ));
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Dio web error"),
        ),
        body: BlocBuilder<MyBloc, MyState>(
            bloc: BlocProvider.of<MyBloc>(context),
            builder: (context, state) {
              return Center(
                  child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    state.status,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () =>
                        BlocProvider.of<MyBloc>(context).add(Event()), // <-- THIS DOESN'T WORK 2ND TIME 
                    child: Text("start"),
                  ),
                ],
              ));
            }));
  }
}

class MyBloc extends Bloc<Event, MyState> {
  @override
  MyState get initialState => MyState("begin");

  @override
  Stream<MyState> mapEventToState(Event event) async* {
    print("handle event");
    try {
      yield MyState("loading...");
      Dio dio = Dio();
      var result = await dio.get("http://does.not.exist/");
      print(result);
      yield MyState("ok");
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e);
      yield MyState("error"); // <-- Error is properly caught and state is generated
    }
  }
}

class Event {}

class MyState {
  final String status;

  MyState(this.status);
}
```

My flutter version: Channel beta, v1.17.0-3.2.pre
Android studio 3.6.3

EDIT:
I have found out that this works fine when running "flutter build web" and serving content with sth like python SimpleHTTPServer.

I can only reproduce issue when running on chrome from android studio

Comment: it is working completely fine but response is quick so we are not able to visualise loading state second time. before calling dio.get if you put future.delay then you will notice it clearly.

Comment: hmm, ok, I've found out that it works fine when I run "flutter build web" and serve content with something like python SimpleHTTPServer, however when starting chrome with android studio I can still reproduce this issue